# Topic for attribute exploration

Tags: algorithms

I'm writing my bachelor theses about the interactive algorithm 'attribute exploration'. 
For this I want to add an example. In the literature I found many such examples, like exploration of finite groups, graphs, rings, ...

I don't want to copy such an example, I want to find a different field, to create my own example.

Any ideas on a good context for such an task. Basically I need a set of objects (mathematical objects preferred, also possible something in CS) and a set of possible attributes.

I thought of using matrices. The attribute can be symmetric, diagonal, orthogonal, rotation matrix, invertable, ...

Any other topics?

Answer (score 1):

In the early of Stumme they used graphs. Have you managed to find something?

http://www.kde.cs.uni-kassel.de/stumme/papers/1995/P1781-GfKl95.pdf
It is one of the works on the topic. The domain for exploration is types of graphs.
The modern one by Robert Jaeschke and S. Rudolph.
It contains some connections to user queries, the paper is referenced below:
http://www.qucosa.de/fileadmin/data/qucosa/documents/11313/019.pdf